# How to get text from text files and show it in textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am using asp.net webforms. I use UploadFile control to load text files and I need to load different text files txt, doc, pdf etc... I only need to get text from files should ignore any images and when get the plain text show it in TextBox1

I have used StreamReader to read the files...

```
protected void UploadText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

      StreamReader readTextFile = new StreamReader(FileUpload1.FileContent, Encoding.Unicode);
        TextBox1.Text = readTextFile.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

here is the uploadfile control:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

It reads the files but it can not get the plain text from the files it shows up many different character codes. I tried Encode.Utf8/Encode.Unicode/Encode.ASCII but still can not display the plain text in TextBox1. Is there any enocode/decode/convert solution to get plain text from any text type files?

Comment: A textfile typically will not tell you how it was encoded. You will need to know beforehand by other means or guess. A good guess is typically Utf8 and rather not Utf-16 (Unicode here means Utf-16)

Comment: none of them works for me especially when it is about pdf files..

Comment: A pdf is not a textfile (for me). If you need plaintext extraction from different sources you might want to take a look at products that do that and have an API. Apache Tika for example. Windows itself has iFilter(s) for that. But thats feels more or less dead.

Comment: _"I need to load different text files txt, doc, pdf etc..."_ I think you are mistaken about what a "text file" _is_. DOC and PDF _may_ contain text, but _they are not simply plain text_ in some encoding (like ascii, utf8, utf16, ...). For each of those there most probably are ways and tools to _extract_ their plain text content but they will need to be handled _very specifically_ and each one differently. In case of PDF even in much more than one way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first up, you can't lump a text file, a pdf file, and say a word document INTO THE SAME sentence!!!

For example, to write code, you need the ability to "discern" the difference between say a cat, and say Mount Everest.

So, this is mount Everest:

[image]

And this is say a cat:

[image]

So, can you see that a cat and a mountain are differing things?

So, just like the above lesson in logic?

You need the SAME ability as above to write computer code.

So, then:

A PDF is VAST different then a text file.

A word doc is VAST different then a text file

A PDF is VAST different then a word document file.

Can you grasp the above logic?

So, you need some software to read a PDF and extract text.

And you need some software to extract text from a word document.

And a text file? Well, that's already text, so that will not really require any software.

So, simple logic dictates here that each file type will have to be dealt with, and you will require software that can read or consume or "deal with" these VAST different types of file formats.

For pdfs? I suggest GhostScript.net, that's a good way to pull/extract text from a pdf. It has a text processor that will pull out text (and ignore graphics) as part of GhostScript.net.

For word docs? Well this again DEPENDS VERY much on what kind of word document.

If the word document is a docx (been that way since 2007 - a whopping 16 years ago!!), then the text part can be extracted with ease, since those documents are saved as a .zip file, and if you re-name a docx file to .zip, then you can open the zip archive, and inside you find the xml part that is TEXT only.

However, if you going to support word doc files, they are a closed "binary" format from Microsoft. So, while word docx files are open xml standards, and with great ease you can extract the text, the doc files are a VERY different matter. In that case, you are probably best to use a doc to docx converter. You could consider installing word on the web server, but that setup not really supported.

## Edit: Some working code examples:

First example, a word document. Say this:

[image]

so this markup:

```
        <h4>Read Word doc text</h4>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdWord" runat="server" Text="Read word text"
            OnClick="cmdWord_Click"
            />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
            TextMode="MultiLine" Height="235px" Width="377px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
```

nuget library:

[image]

code for button:

```
    protected void cmdWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sWordFile = @"c:\test\Example.docx";
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sWordFile,false))
        {
            string sText = "";

            // get all text - no line breaks
            // sText = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText;


            // get all text - line breaks
            var MySections 
                = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<Paragraph>();

            foreach (Paragraph MySection in MySections)
                sText += MySection.InnerText + System.Environment.NewLine;

            TextBox1.Text = sText;

        }

    }
```

Result:

[image]

Read text from PDF.

library: GhostScript.net  (nuget)

[image]

(you need a copy of the gsdll) from actual ghostscript libary:

markup:

```
        <h4>Read PDF doc text</h4>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdPDF" runat="server" Text="Read PDF text"
            OnClick="cmdPDF_Click"
            />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Height="235px" Width="377px"></asp:TextBox>
```

code behind:

```
    protected void cmdPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // pdf extract
        string sPDFFile = @"c:\test\Example.pdf";

        string sText = "";
        sText = GetPDFText(sPDFFile);
        TextBox2.Text = sText;

    }

    public string GetPDFText(string strPDF)
    {

        Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptVersionInfo gVER;
        // get locaiton of dll
        string strgDLL = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\MyDLL\gsdll64.dll";
        gVER = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(new Version(0, 0, 0), strgDLL, "", Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptLicense.GPL);

        using (Ghostscript.NET.Processor.GhostscriptProcessor gP = new Ghostscript.NET.Processor.GhostscriptProcessor(gVER, true))
        {
            using (Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptPipedOutput gpH = new Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptPipedOutput())
            {
                string outputPieHande = "%handle%" + int.Parse(gpH.ClientHandle).ToString("X2");

                List<string> Myargs = new List<string>();
                {
                    Myargs.Add("-empty");
                    Myargs.Add("-dSAFER");
                    Myargs.Add("-dBATCH");
                    Myargs.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
                    Myargs.Add("-dNOPROMPT");
                    Myargs.Add("-dFirstPage=1");
                    Myargs.Add("-sDEVICE=txtwrite");
                    Myargs.Add("-dNEWPDF=false");
                    Myargs.Add("-dNumRenderingThreads=4");
                    Myargs.Add("-sOutputFile=" + outputPieHande);
                    Myargs.Add("-q");      // quiet mode
                    Myargs.Add("-f");
                    Myargs.Add(strPDF);
                }

                try
                {
                    gP.StartProcessing(Myargs.ToArray(), null);
                    byte[] raw = null;

                    raw = gpH.Data;
                    var strOut = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
                    gpH.Dispose();
                    return strOut;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Print("my exception " + ex.Message);
                    return "threadexit";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Document example:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: You have such a great attitude here, that I going to post my code for this. Take a look at my edit above. I have posted sample posted code. I show a word example, and a PDF example.

Comment: Thanks DocumentFormat.OpenXML works fine but Ghostscript when run the code is asking for native library where should I put gsdll to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, in my example, I created a folder called MyDLL, and I tend to dump "most" of my .dlls into that folder. Make sure you right click on the .dlls you add to that folder, and choose Content and "copy always".  I suppose you could use the bin folder, but in this case, we are "loading" the .dll for ghostscript  to work correctly. There are other ways, but this was a git-hub friendly way that worked for me.

Comment: I have installed Ghostscript.net through nuget package manager 'Version 1.2.3', in the package folder found the DLL file called Ghostscript.NET.dll and copy - pasted in MyDLL folder  and added the path to my code: @"\MyDLL\Ghostscript.NET.dll" and got this error-> Module could not be loaded, I also tried with bin folder put the DLL file and add the path @"\bin\Ghostscript.NET.dll" still got the same error...

Comment: Didn't ever talk about the. Net .dll, I specifically said the. Dll from ghostscipt,  the one in my sample code - specifically gsdll64.dll. that's not a .net .dll and I also specifically stated you need to install ghostscipt in addition to ghostscipt. Net.  It's after installing gs that you are to make a copy of that gsdll64.dll into the mydll folder.  You don't necessarily have to do it this way but come deployments time you no really be able to install ghostscipt on the web server.  Don't confuse ghostscipt.net with separate requirements to also install ghostscipt on your computer.

Comment: Now it is working just almost fine the only problem is that sometimes it is working slow is that normal? Is this Ghostscript free to use in my website if I run it for commercial purposes i am just asking cause I am new to it and I am self teaching programming learner?

Comment: Don't know the licensing requirements, you have to check their site as licensing is a complex issue. As for speed? Gee, I suppose it depends on how large the PDF file is, and how much text to extract.  I actually start a separate process thread (say after a PDF file up-load), and that separate thread does the text extraction and saves the text to a database. So yes, that pdf text extraction can take a few seconds - certainly something that you probably can't do in real time, and thus I don't (I consider it a type of batch processing).

Comment: also, I tend to ONLY pull the first page for the text preview, and that way, evne for a large PDF, it takes VERY little time (less then 1 second). So add to the parameter's this:                         Myargs.Add("-dFirstPage=1"); and Myargs.Add("-dLastPage=1"); So, even for a 100 page document, it takes less then 1 second, and I only really need the text from the first page for a preview anyway.